# How to randomly print contents of a Vector in Java?

Tags: java, random, vector

I need to print the contents of a Vector in random order without duplicates in Java. I have this so far:

```
 for(int p = 0; p < v.size(); p++) {
        boolean print = true;
        int n = Math.abs(r.nextInt() % v.size());
        Vector<Integer> printed = new Vector<Integer>();
        if(printed.contains(n))
            print = false;
        if(print)
            System.out.println(v.elementAt(n));
        printed.addElement(n);
    }
```

where "v" is my String Vector and "r" is my random generator (seeded by the time). It prints in random order, but still prints duplicates.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, why don't you use a Set? Also I don't know why you use `contains` and `elementAt` with `n`. contains check if the `Integer` is not in the vector, and `elementAt` returns the element at the index given.

Comment: your printed vector is being instantiated inside the loop, that means each iteration would give a new vector, and are not kept persistent, try having it outside the loop.

Comment: From the [JavaDoc for `Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) _If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector_. Don't use `Vector`. Ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections.shuffle(vector)
Then take output and put it in a set (don't use SortedSet).
You've now randomized and removed duplicates.

Comment: This is a really good answer. Perhaps as an improvement you want to add everything to a Set first, then shuffle. If there are a lot of duplicates this might make a significant performance difference.

Comment: Not only is de-duping first more efficient, but shuffling your list *then* putting it into a `HashSet` or similar will effectively eliminate the randomness introduced by shuffling.  Guava's `ImmutableSet` does preserve insertion order, however `Set`s cannot be expected to provide that guarantee in general, and the ordering of `HashSet` is not random.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, there is no reason to use [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).  It has been effectively deprecated since Java 1.2, more than [*15 years ago*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.2_.28December_8.2C_1998.29).  Use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

Note also that calling `Random.nextInt() % max` is an anti-pattern, breaking the randomness of your generator.  Always call `Random.nextInt(max)` if you want an Integer in a smaller range than `Random.nextInt()` - the latter method is designed to do the right thing and give you an even distribution.

---

Ok, so you want to strip duplicates, and you also want to print in an arbitrary (or do you literally mean random?) order.

The easiest way to accomplish both goals is with a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).  Common `Set` implementations, notably [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), are explicitly unordered, meaning the order they are added in is not necessarily the order they are returned.

So you could simply do the following:

```
List<Integer> ls = ...;
for(Integer i : new HashSet<Integer>(ls)) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

However like I said, there is a difference between an arbitrary order, and properly random.  `HashSet` is arbitrary, but there are potentially predictable patterns in its implementation, such that the output of the above code could not be called "random".

If you really want random ordering, your best bet is the [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) function, which takes a list and shuffles it, so that each element is approximately equally likely to be in any position in the list.  Here's some example code (note we have to *first* put it through a `HashSet` to strip duplicates):

```
List<Integer> ls = ...;
ls = new ArrayList<Integer>(new HashSet<Integer>(ls));
Collections.shuffle(ls);
for(Integer i : ls) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

This will print the unique elements of `ls` in a random* order.

<sub>*Technically, it is pseudo-random, but there's no need to worry about that.  It's random enough.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, guys. I have to use a vector for my assignment, unfortunately.  I ended up using an array of booleans to check if I had already printed the string: 
`boolean[] check = new boolean[v.size()];
for(int a = 0; a < check.length; a++)

check[a] = false;

int printed = 0;

do {

int n = Math.abs(r.nextInt() % check.length);

if(check[n] == false) {

System.out.println(v.elementAt(n));

check[n] = true;

printed++;

}

}while(printed < v.size());`

Comment: You can post a solution that works for you as another answer to this question, no need to bury your code in a comment.  Note that my answer works just as well with `Vector` as `ArrayList`, so you can substitute `Vector` above if you need to.  Note also however that using `Vector` essentially marks you as uninformed and behind the times.  I would never hire someone who attempted to use this class in production code, and any assignment requiring the use of `Vector` is actively doing you and your classmates a disservice.

Comment: Additionally, you're still doing `r.nextInt() % check.length`, this is just wrong.  Use [`Random.nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your Vector like so:

```
Vector<Integer> printed = new Vector<Integer>();
```

and then you check if `printed` contains something:

```
if(printed.contains(n))
```

But, you just initialized `printed` to contain zero elements.

Thus, `printed.contains(n)` will **always** be `false`.

As such, `print` will never be set to `false` and all of the elements in `v` will be printed to the console.